# find and rm extra srt files

Tags: find, rm, lang, srt

I want to find and remove all *.srt files that are extra. If in the video directory there is an *.en.srt file then I want to rm that file, if not then leave it.

So I figured out this:

```
find /share/CACHEDEV4_DATA/Movies -name "*.srt" ! -name "*.en.srt" -type f -exec rm -v {} \;
```

Will find and remove them all but I don't know how to keep the ones that are solo.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't `rm *.srt` be sufficient ?

Comment: No I don't want to delete "ALL" the srt files just the ones that are NOT solo in the directory. So if a language file exists then don't delete.

Comment: Okay I shall rephrase. No that command would not be sufficient as it would delete all the "srt" files.